# How to solve Angular [object object] in template

Tags: json, angular

I am getting [object object] showing in my html page.

I am calling the a web service and in my console.log. I can see the full response but on my template I only see [object object]

```
test() {

 this.http.post('api...', JSON.stringify(this.getAllCaseInfoWithCAS)).subscribe(data => {  
  this.testData = [data];
 });

}
```

I have a ngFor

```
<ng-template ngbPanelContent>
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of testData">  
   {{item.getAllCaseInfoWithCASReturn.caseDetails}}
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

The response looks like this

```
{
    "getAllCaseInfoWithCASReturn": {
        "caseDetails": {
            "caseNumber": "12345",
            "componentDetails": {
                "component": "29"
            },
            "personNumber": "5",
            "month": "7"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I display all the information on the template?

Comment: try using `{{item.getAllCaseInfoWithCASReturn.caseDetails.toString()}}`

Comment: {{ item.getAllCaseInfoWithCASReturn.caseDetails | json }}. Also, read the guide about the HttpClient. You don't need to call JSON.stringify. HttpCLient does that for you, and sets the correct content-type header.

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal I still get the same issue

Comment: Why are you making the result as an array explicitly (`this.testData = [data]`), can you provide an example with more than one `caseDetails` if you have that? Also explain how you want to display the data.

Comment: @sabithpocker If I don't do [data] then I get this error "Cannot find a differ supporting object of type 'object'". I just want to display the data in a list(not important at the moment how it shows). I only have 1 case at this point in time.

Comment: @skydev Then surely there is no need to use `*ngFor`? And then you don't need to put it in an array

Comment: @user184994 but there will be more cases in the future

Comment: So would you code for one case now and change the code when it become 2 cases? I am saying this because your JSON doesn't seem to support more than one case, even in future.

Comment: @sabithpocker yes, I will just do the one case for now and change it going forward

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` inside your results and look in the browser console what result you receive. This would really help in order to provide a solution.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone, I managed to get it to display by removing the ngFor. It will work for now until the JSON can accommodate more cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe)

```
{{ value_expression | json }}
```

> Converts a value into its JSON-format representation. Useful for debugging.

```
{{ item.getAllCaseInfoWithCASReturn.caseDetails | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better start by making JSON formatted as an array of caseDetails, here is a rough code of what you can do with current JSON:

```
// This should be refactored to a service file.
getCaseDetails(data: any): Observable<any[]> {
    const url = `api/url`;
    return this.httpClient.post(url, data)
        .pipe(
            map(result => result['getAllCaseInfoWithCASReturn']['caseDetails']),
            tap(caseDetail => console.log(caseDetail))
        )
}

test() {
    this.getCaseDetails(dummyData).subscribe(caseDetail => {
        this.testData = caseDetail;
    })
}
```

---

```
<ng-template ngbPanelContent>
 <div class="row">  
   {{testData?.caseNumber}} <!-- or json pipe -->
   {{testData?.personNumber}}
   {{testData?.month}}
   {{testData?.componentDetails?.component}}
 </div>
</ng-template>
```